# mui datagrid get all rows for datagrid table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

How can I access all of the rows in the datagrid in the form of an array, for example, we normally have 100 data, we filtered the datagrid, 20 data remained, how can I reach that 20 data?